# How do I make my enemies to follow a path and allow them to collide with the player in Game Maker?

Tags: collision-detection, game-maker

I am making a game in which enemies follow a path. These enemies should be colliding with the player, but it's not working.

The enemy is walking the path. And, I want to make it so if the player collides with the enemy, the game restarts the level. Game Maker doesn't let me collide my player with the enemy at all!

How could I make my enemy that follows a path collide with the player?

I'm using Game Maker: Studio.

Comment: You could provide more details, or I don't know enough about game maker, but did you see [this](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/movement%20and%20collisions/collisions/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

In order to collide objects, make sure the player **object** and the baddy **object** both have the **property** of

> solid

.

Then add the **event**

> collision: player

and give that **event** the **action** that restarts the level.